# How to create Tomcat keystore file using JAVA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, selenium, keystore

How to create Tomcat keystore file using JAVA

I am creating a http connection to SSL enabled tomcat server but it generates error SSL Handshake failed

So I want to create a keystore at runtime as i will be contacting multiple SSL enabled servers (Don't know this approach will be successfull or not)

Please suggest a way to how to create a tomcat keystore file using java program or any other way to bypass SSL handshake

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting sslhandshake error exactly? While client wants to connect to tomcat server or while tomcat server is trying to connect to other servers for some purpose? And can you paste the exception trace?

In either case, it does not make any sense to create keystore programatically in a server but one can inspect java's keytool source code to play on keystores.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the How-To guide SSL configuration on Tomcat's official site

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: this link does not contain any information regarding creating keystore dynamically/using java programatically